# How to make ag-grid column as wide as largest text in column

Tags: javascript, html, css, ag-grid

I wanna remove those gaps which I marked with black line.Because I wanna `sizeToFit` and when I add new columns to dataset,I dont wanna see texts in these columns with .... .

[image]

Plunkr example: https://plnkr.co/edit/510MSisTzhw4t6Cy

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `gridOptions.columnApi.autoSizeColumns` at initialisation time:

```
function autoSizeAll(skipHeader) {
  var allColumnIds = [];
  gridOptions.columnApi.getAllColumns().forEach(function(column) {
    allColumnIds.push(column.colId);
  });

  gridOptions.columnApi.autoSizeColumns(allColumnIds, skipHeader);
}
```

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-resizing/#auto-size-columns